# SUM() of CASE WHEN mysql query ignores limit

Tags: mysql

I have a total of 4 rows. The team ID 500 has 3 wins, 1 loss.

The query below, is expected to return a max of 2 results, a record of either, 2-0, or 1-1 depending if it was DESC or ASC.

I keep getting the results of 3 & 1. I'm not sure where to add the limit.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `winner` = 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `loser` = 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS losses
FROM  `schedule`
WHERE  500 IN (`winner`, `loser`)
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: could you show all the actual data from your table?

Comment: You need a group by I think

Comment: @Darryl Allen You'll get your answer within minutes, just post the table structure and table data (select *) for schedule.

Comment: @VishwanathDalvi I agree. Allen Post your table structure and the data of the table. I can visualize the query but dont know what you have, what you need and why you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, to achieve your goal you have to apply `LIMIT` in a subquery.
And the reason for that is that `LIMIT` applies last in the process of gathering the resultset.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `winner` = 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `loser`  = 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS losses
FROM  
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM schedule 
   WHERE  500 IN (`winner`, `loser`)
   ORDER BY `date` DESC
   LIMIT 2
) q
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3c61/3)** demo.

Comment: peterm - you rocked it. ty